# mysql in docker won't connect with my nodejs API on my host

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

it has been a long day and i don't know why i am stuck at this problem for such a long time so any help is very much appreciated!

my problem is the famus code: 'ECONNREFUSED' which suddenly appeared for my project. i am trying to run a mysql db with PMA in docker and trying to connect to it from my nodejs (not in docker but on host) to get a fetch response but everything that i try and any suggestion i look at i find no solution! so any idea at this point would help me greatly and get me to bed sooner.

i cut the story short and put my codes here please do let me know with any tips, thanks in advance!

this is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const apiroutes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/data', apiroutes);

app.listen('3000', ()=>{
    console.log('server is running on port: 3000');
});
```

this is my routes file

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db');

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', async(req, res, next)=>{

    try{
        let results = await db.all();
        res.json(results);
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});


module.exports = router;
```

this is my db file

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    password: 'secret',
    user: 'user',
    database: 'db_test',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306'
});

let wholeDB = {};

wholeDB.all = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM table1`,(error, result)=>{

            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }

            return resolve(result);

        });

    });

};
module.exports = wholeDB;
```

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

and finaly this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  vuePhP:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginxWebServer
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php
    networks:
      - vuePhP


  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysqlService
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - vuePhP

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpMyAdmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - vuePhP

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: phpService
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - vuePhP
```

and this is the error that i get when i use postman to do a get command

> errno: -111,   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 3306,   fatal: true

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)

thank you!

edit: i have added the port 4306 to the node app and get this error :

> code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',   errno: 1251,   sqlMessage:
> 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server;
> consider upgrading MySQL client',   sqlState: '08004',   fatal: true

i added this line in my compose file but it didn't help:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysqlService
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: KFV_test
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - vuePhP
```

Comment: You've set the host port mapping for MySQL to 4306. That's the port you need to be using in your Node app

Comment: i have tried to map other ports to mysql to test but nothing worked, even same ports and btw my node app is not in docker and express put it on port 3000.

Comment: In your compose file, you have `- "4306:3306"` in the [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for the mysql service. In your `db.js` file, you have `port: '3306'` but if your Node app is running on the host, that needs to be `port: 4306`

Comment: thank you for your response, i should say that i have tried it just now and now iget this error, code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE'. and a long sql message. sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client'. but my sql is latest and i don't know where else i should give authorization, i am googeling as we speak.

Comment: That one's simple ~ https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2499. I'd recommend the `mysql2` library or even something more exotic like Sequelize

Comment: i am working on that, thanks for the suggestion. i will update this post if anything happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah i found it, the problem is the version of mysql in composer and usage of mysql library instead of mysql2 as Phil graciously mentioned. so i downgraded mysql version by version until i found the one that worked and before that added mysql2 (npm i mysql2) to my nodejs app. and it worked. here my is my changes in docker-compose file. btw changed the ports as well not that it helped before the downgrade.

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    container_name: mysqlService
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - vuePhP
```

and changed the connection method in my db file:
const mysql2 = require('mysql2');

```
const connection = mysql2.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'db_test',
  });

let wholeDB = {};

wholeDB.all = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM table1`,(error, result)=>{

            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }

            return resolve(result);

        });

    });

};
module.exports = wholeDB;
```

Comment: _"changed the ports as well not that it helped"_... Lol, it only completely changed the error you were getting

Comment: until you downgrade mysql on docker no port changing will help and i think if you have stated what port on your js file you can copy past that in docker as well, right? the only reason i changed docker-compose was because of mysql2 lib in my js and i didin't wanted to add more properties to it than what was in doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "dbName",
  port : "3306"
})
connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }
    if (connection) connection.release()
    return
})
module.exports = connection
```

example :

```
import connection from '../Modules/connection.js';
    let LoginQuery = (values) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // let sql =  `SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE mobile_number ="${values.mobile_number}" OR email_id="${values.mobile_number}"`;
        let sql =  "SELECT * FROM `admin_tbl` WHERE mobile_number = ? OR email_id = ?";
            connection.query(sql, Object.values(values), (err, result) => {
                console.log(err);
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
            });
        });
    };
```

Please use this connecting pool hope it'll work.

Comment: thank you for your help but i think my solution to downgrade mysql in docker-compose works better. i think the normal mysql lib would work too i just don't have time to check it but thanks again.